# Maximum number of products can be entered into website on Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Previously on my last job, the System Ayalyst said **Magento CE** (still in M1 era) can only support up to **20000 products**, while EE can support unlimited products. But I can't find any references to support this statement.

I'd know the maximum products limits of Magento 2.X (as I only use this in my current job now) on both CE and EE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Magento 2 can handle as many products as you want for Both CE and EE.
- It might take some time to upload these products.
- It might even make your website slow depending on the hosting
  provider.
- It even depends on database you are using on back-end, MYSQL is
  relatively slow when querying large data.
- You might want some good database for example: Mysql-Percona,Oracle.

> But Yes magento2 EE have split database structure so when we have
>   large catalog size it won't effect on performance Compare to CE. in CE when
>   we have more than 1 lakh(100 Thousands(100k))  products it will make website bit slower.But it still depends on the Technology stack(Server and its configuration) which you are using.

**One line conclusion there is no catalog limit with magento2 CE or EE**

Comment: What is "1 lakh" on your quote?

Comment: 1lakh = 100 Thousands(100k)

Comment: We have an M1 system with over 1000k. So I'm not sure where the support is for only 20k. Takes some time to learn how to manage your servers, but it can handle it with the proper setup.  Magento 2 has a split db structure so you can manage different parts of the db which is nice for clusters, but I'm sure it can handle at lot. How many products are you looking to get? 100k should be no issue with the proper setup.

Comment: Very Good Explain @ManthanDave - It helps me a lot , +1 for  you

Comment: @MakDavid Thank you so much for your words .